# What's the right word to use here?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the word to complete the following sentence

"Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily **_**"

Meaning simplicity doesn't preclude sophistication.

Edit: I am not looking for something that means opposite, they are not opposites of each other obviously.  I am looking for a word which means presence of something doesn't rule out the presence of the other( like presence of high iron rules out anemia ).

Comment: Mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Danielδ single word :). Something similar to oxymoron i guess.

Comment: @Surya - sometimes two words are better than one.

Comment: Simplicity and sophistication are *orthogonal*. Unfortunately, *orthogonal* is unlikely to be in the average person's vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

> Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication. --Leonardo da Vinci

Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily [*incompatible*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=incompatible).

Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily *[contradictory](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=contradictory)*.

Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily *[opposites](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=opposites)*.

Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily *[antithetical](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=antithetical)*.

Comment: I never heard *X and Y are paradoxical* used in that sense.

Answer (score 3):

Simplicity and sophistication are not necessarily **incompatible**.

Answer (score 2):

mutually exclusive.
disjoint.
separate.
opposed.
(and contradictory.)

Set theory's [disjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) is probably the least vulnerable to misinterpretation here.

Comment: Actually I think most people would probably say *mutually exclusive* in this particular context, and *incompatible* in many others. Although I'd understand *disjoint*, it's a rather odd choice of word - I'd probably think more about the speaker's vocabulary than his meaning.

Comment: Yes, you always have to consider your audience. I've been discussing a lot of discrete mathematics these past few weeks.

Comment: haha - I knew it! A mathematician's vocabulary always gives him away! :)